# h5Validate function call should done on form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have validated my form using `http://ericleads.com/h5validate/` . I am calling a js function onsubmit="js();"of a form. The issues is validaion works but the js() function always call first whether the form gets validated or not. What I want that it should check for the validation first and when the form is validated then it should run the js function I am calling onsubmit event. Kindly let me know how can I do that.

```
<form onsubmit="js();">
<input type="text" required />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').h5Validate();
});
```

Comment: call the js() function after the validation succeeds, remove it from onsubmit

Comment: however when you submit the form then only the js() function will be called rite?

Comment: The documentation states that there is a `formValidated` event once the form is validated, but it doesn't say how to use it, or much of anything really, and the plugin seems to generally suck in my opinion ?

Comment: @Shahe I am not able to figure out where to get the validation success part.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys I found the answer from here `http://ericleads.com/2011/12/updated-h5validate-form-validation-plugin-for-jquery/` `var result = $('#form').h5Validate('allValid');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Remove the submit event from html. Add it in javascript.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   var result = $('#form').h5Validate('allValid'); // call the validator function here
   if(result==true)
   {
      js(); // function that you want to call on submit
   }
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: when i alert result it returns `object [object]`

Comment: what are you returning from the validator function ? Generally it should return true or false.. means if the form is validated or not. If you are returning a object. you can also check if(result!=null && result!=undefined).

Comment: from this `var result = h5Validate(); alert(result)` after user clicks on submit

Comment: You're close.  Here's a hint; read the documentation for the linked plugin.

Comment: Can you check. $(‘#myForm’).h5Validate(‘allValid’); This should return true or false. Got this idea from documentation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys I found the answer from here `http://ericleads.com/2011/12/updated-h5validate-form-validation-plugin-for-jquery/` `var result = $('#form').h5Validate('allValid');`

Comment: :) I just told you 1 min ago in my prev comment. Hope my comment and post was useful.

Comment: @ABP You should modify your answer to display the correct information.